# Does "ran to" have a specific ending point in time?

Tags: tenses, simple-past

Consider the following sentence:

> Sam ran to the university pool.

Does the running action have an ending point in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because the action was completed. If the action wasn't completed,  you would have to say

> Sam is running to the university pool.

Comment: Or *was running*, perhaps, in some narrative past continuous.

Comment: I think OP's specific point might be better illustrated by contrasting with *"Sam ran **towards** the university pool."* In that case, for all we know he might *still* not have reached the pool yet, but with *"to"*, the implication is both the *running* and the *getting **to** the pool* are "past" actions.